# Looking for a stable user set up gem for mhartl/railstutoria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, railstutorial.org

Every time I look at Rails it changes.

The only guy who keeps up is mhartl. With his fantastic tutorial.

I'm looking for:

rvm simple-user-template-by-mh

Comment: you should ask mhartl / rvm to provide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is exactly what you need, but I was working hard on this bootstrapping solution to get everything installed what you could need, it's version of RailsInstaller for OSX, we are still doing internal testing but so far no problems were found.

There are available two versions:

1. Snow Leopard => https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/src/RailsInstaller-0.9.6-osx-10.6-installer.app.tar.gz
2. Lion => https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/src/RailsInstaller-0.9.6-osx-10.7-installer.app.tar.gz

On fresh OSX machine download it, run it - and enter all the data needed, click install - go grab a coffee or two ... ... ... ...

Installer will setup all the required libraries, ruby-1.9.3, rails 3.2 for you and show you some basic information about it.

In case of any problems you can find me on #rvm irc channel on freenode servers, or open ticket here: https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix

---

EDIT1:
here is Michael's sample app: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed

I already asked the team to include the app in RIX, also I asked Michael if we could work on including a command in RVM to bootstrap it for you (with all it needs).

Comment: thanks for the link to github!